# Changing the ViewModel's property from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have the ListBox on my MainView.xaml, selecting the Item forces the ContentControl to display different UserControls. I use Caliburn.Micro library in this propgram. Here's some code:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemsListBox" SelectedItem="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TextBlock1Text}" x:Name="TextBlock1"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=ItemsListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content}" />
```

The **MainViewModel.cs**:

```
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }
    private string _textBlock1Text;
    public string TextBlock1Text
    {
        get => _textBlock1Text;
        set
        {
            _textBlock1Text = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextBlock1Text);
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TextBlock1Text = "Test";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemsModel>()
        {
            new ItemsModel { Name="Useless", Content=null },
            new ItemsModel { Name="TextChangerViewModel", Content=new TextChangerViewModel(TextBlock1Text) }
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemsModel> Items { get; set; }
```

The **ItemsModel.cs**:

```
    public class ItemsModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Content { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the **TextChangerViewModel.cs**:

```
    public class TextChangerViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private string _textBlock1Text;

    public string TextBlock1Text
    {
        get => _textBlock1Text;
        set
        {
            _textBlock1Text = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TextBlock1Text);
        }
    }

    public TextChangerViewModel(string textBlock1Text) //passing parameter from another ViewModel
    {
        TextBlock1Text = textBlock1Text;
    }
}
```

So, the **main question** is how to change the TextBlock1Text (and the Text value of TextBlock in .xaml as well) in the MainViewModel.cs from the TextChangerViewModel.cs? I was thinking about using something like NotifyCollectionChanged on my Items ObservableCollection, but it work with collection of ItemsModel, not with the VM's, so I'm stuck here.

I'm also not sure if having `public object Content { get; set; }` in ItemsModel.cs is a good thing if I'm targeting the MVVM pattern, but I don't know the other way to do it (I'm very new to MVVM).

**UPD**

I'm looking for the property-changing way because I need to change the TextBlock1Text Text from another UserControl. Suppose I have the button on my  **TextChangerView.xaml**: `<Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Change da text" cal:Message.Attach="ChangeTextButton"/>`

And after the click on it I want the text on the parental MainView.xaml to change. But the thing is, I don't know how to change properties in this case, as I wrote above why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the the binding of textblox1 to reference the selected item.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemsListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" x:Name="TextBlock1"/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemsListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Content.TextBlock1Text}" x:Name="TextBlock1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good approach, but I was looking for the property-changing way. Let's have an expand this example. Suppose I have button on my TextChangerView.xaml, and I want the click on this button cause TextBlock1Text (on the parental MainView.xaml) Text to change. I'll update the question too, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you trying to access a property in the TextChangerViewModel? I added an example to do that.

Comment: Yes, that seems to solve my problem, thanks. That means I don't need the TextBlockText1 property in MainViewModel.cs? That seems weird not to have corresponding property in VM (for the element in the current View), but have it in the subsidiary VM.